# Sparse matrix storage space

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I need to get the storage size of sparse matrix in amount of double numbers. I need to get this information in runtime.

Comment: what is your underlying problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nonzero elements are stored, alongside with their row indices, so

```
nnz(x);
```

is a good approximation, as it returns the [number of nonzero elements](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html).

If your sparse matrix is getting unexpectedly big, you can check `nnz` to keep track of a bug which may result in overwriting a lot of zero elements.

So the effectiveness of using sparse matrices can be also measured with

```
s=size(m_sparse);
effectiveness = 1 - nnz(x)/(s(1)*s(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the command `whos` to get the space used by a variable.

http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/whos.html

```
whos var_name

info=whos('var_name');
```